# when using Jmeter to test websocket stomp, cannot send connect message correctly

Tags: jmeter, stomp

I installed **websocket** stomp sampler plugin to **Jmeter**, and new a stomp sampler to test the server. but when I filled the connect message as the message

I got from the developer:

```
CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000
host: qa.so.aws.mxj.mx

^@
```

The **Jmeter** gave `400 error` and said

> "- Connect or Subscribe Paylod Message are empty"

When I saw the request from **Jmeter**, it said:

> ["CONNECT\n\n\u0000"]

I don't know how to let Jmeter to get the correct connect message, please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving both Connect Message and subscribe message.

Example:
**Connect Message**

```
CONNECT\naccept-version:1.1\nheart-beat:0,0
```

**Subscribe Message**

```
SUBSCRIBE\nid:sub-0\ndestination:/topic/queue
```

Select both the check boxes Streaming connection and stomp protocol along with other details (host, port, protocol, path, connection and response timeout).